# C# Custom Fonts not working in Xamarin Forms (Android). Xamarin 4.8. Windows 10, VS19

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, fonts

I'm having an issue with Xamarin Forms 4.8 custom fonts.

I've followed the guides to the letter, that is:

-Loaded my font files (.ttf or .otf) into my shared directory and marked them as Embedded resources.

-Added the ExportFont outside of my namespace.

When I reference the font anywhere it just builds the standard font. Here is a snippet of code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: ExportFont("Stencil.ttf")]
[assembly: ExportFont("GreatVibes.otf")]
[assembly: ExportFont("Lobster-Regular.ttf", Alias= "MyFont")]

namespace BAAaM
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {

            Grid topgrid = new Grid();
            topgrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Test, please work", FontSize = 30, FontFamily = "Lobster-Regular" }, 0, 1);
this.Content = topgrid;
}
}
}
```

I've experimented placing the fonts into my Android directory, under assets but that doesn't work either. Is Xamarin overwriting whatever I do with standard Font as part of the built in label functions? I have no problems changing the text size.

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue.

My solution: Changing file structure

FROM:
Assets/Fonts/PoppinsBold.ttf

To:
Fonts/PoppinsBold.ttf

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to [this official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithfonts/) to check whether it works first.

Then I tested with your shared code:

```
    public FontPageXaml ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        Grid topgrid = new Grid();
        topgrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Test, please work", FontSize = 30, FontFamily = "Lobster-Regular" }, 0, 1);
        this.Content = topgrid;
    }
```

And it works:

[image]